# Do something when animation is ready.

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a animation in my navigationbased application.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
                                       forView:self.view cache:YES];        
        [UIImageView commitAnimations];
```

Directly after this bit of code i call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

The thing is, I don't want to pop my ViewController before my animation is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set animations delegate and didStop selector and pop your view controller in that didStop method you specify:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
                                       forView:self.view cache:YES];        
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
```

Note, that didStop selector must be of the form specified in docs (see `+ setAnimationDidStopSelector` method in docs for more details):

> selector should be of the form: -
>   (void)animationDidStop:(NSString
>   *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a selector to be called when the animation is finished:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
```

And in that selector call the pop the view controller.

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

       // Pop the controller now
    }
```